# Vue $on is not picking up my event when I trigger $emit

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a vue instance set as a global variable called todoEventBus.

When my component is created I set $on to trigger an alert when I emit an event called "pluralise".

My component has a button which triggers this pluralise event.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
    <div class="todo-item">

        <!--// -->

        <button @click="pluralise">Plural</button>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "todo-item",
    props: {
        // props
        todo: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },

    data() {
       // data
       'title': this.todo.title,
    },


    created() {
        todoEventBus.$on('pluralise', alert());
    },

    methods: {

        pluralise() {
            todoEventBus.$emit('pluralise.')
        },

        handlePluralise() {
            this.title = this.title + 's';
        }
    },


}
</script>
```

When I click the pluralise button I see the following event get emitted:

```
name:"pluralise."
type:"$emit"
source:"<Root>"
payload:Array[0]
```

But no alert gets triggered so this todoEventBus.$on is not picking up the event.

Comment: The emitted event name has a `.` at the end, so it doesn't match the `$on` event name.

Comment: Well there's two hours I am not getting back. Thank you for spotting that.